# How can I install django debug toolbar?

Tags: python, django

I use ubuntu and I installed the django debug toolbar with pip using `sudo pip install django-debug-toolbar`. Then I added it to my settings file. Now when I start the django app server I get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./social/manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named debug_toolbar
(kthsocial)dac@dac-VPCSA2Z9E:/etc/social/social$ ./social/manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./social/manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/home/dac/.virtualenvs/kthsocial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named debug_toolbar
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Check your site packages. Did it install? Is there any debug_toolbar folder there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `sudo pip install django-debug-toolbar` never installed `django-debug-toolbar`  in your virtualenv. Make sure your virtualenv is activate and use `pip install django-debug-toolbar`. Don't use `sudo`

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `sudo` to install things when you're in a virtualenv.